# Gap between number line and text buffer

Tags: line-numbers

Is there a way to specify the gap between the number line column and the text buffer. The defaults are too close to my liking.

Comment: I believe it is not possible in Vim. More details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2534520/329318).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible in Vim.

You can use the `numberwidth` option to control the size of the number column but Vim formats the number adding only one space after the number.

More details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2534520/329318).